# Where did the missing magazines go from my magazine rack?

Tags: fallout-4

I decided to craft a magazine rack to go next to my Bobblehead Stand and waste an hour displaying all the magazines I've found in the wasteland (the wooden magazine rack, because getting them into that was only extremely hard but getting them into the metal one seemed to be impossible!)

After many more hours of play I noticed that the magazines were not where I left them, several had fallen down onto the bottom or onto the floor, and some where missing completely. I picked them all up and put them back in the workshop, but I'm missing Hot Rodder, an issue of Total Hack, one issue of Taboo Tattoos, two issues of Tales of a Junktown Jerky Vendor, and at least one issue of Wasteland Survival Guide (I can't remember how many I have found).  I also thought I was missing one part of "View from the Vault" but that had just fallen behind the magazine rack, so I found it when I moved the rack.

I know I don't lose the perk if I lose the magazine, and I don't need the caps I could get from selling them, but it's annoying that after wasting an hour trying to make my settlement look nice with a magazine rack I end up losing them.

I assume the magazines got knocked out of place by an idiot settler stumbling around trying to find their bed, but where could the missing ones be?

Is someone likely to have picked them up?

Could they have gone back to their original spawn points? (And even if not, could I find a second copy by going back to those places?)

Is this just another bug in this flawed but still great game?

Comment: Little side note, you don't have to manually place them on the rack. Use the racks as any container and transfer the magazines from your inventory into it. The magazines will automagically appear perfectly placed in the rack. The metal one will even spin while it's getting filled.

Comment: I'm impressed, you really spent an hour getting the magazines on the rack manually one by one?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, well now I feel stupid :)

Comment: If you are ok with playing modded game I would recommend to try and use this mod https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/12454. It will allow you to lock you magazine rack and theoretically no one should be able to take anything from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settlers will [steal your stuff if you leave it around in the open](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/248036/52800). I had a similar issue with a shelf full of bobble heads and over time several of those went walkies as well. The same applies to power armor you leave with fusion cores in them or, if the settler has a fusion core of their own and a reason to steal it...

This applies to unlocked containers as well, whether this is intentional behavior or not, or whether it will be fixed. <strike>However, settlers don't seem to be able to take anything out of workshop storage</strike> They'll even steal out of workshop storage.

Another point worth noting is that in many instances the individual that stole the item will still have it in their inventory, if you can find them and trade with them you may be able to get them back.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go through every settlers' pockets then, like naughty children! Are the bobbleheads safe on the Bobblehead Stand?

Comment: I haven't tested too extensively, I just store all of mine in the Workshop, but based on what you're saying they're taking them off the magazine rack so I don't see why not. Unless of course your issue was that they fell off the magazine stand first...

Comment: As I noted [elsewhere](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247649/how-do-i-stop-my-settlers-stealing-my-weapons-and-armour/247699#comment342284_247649) settlers _can_ take things from the workshop, but maybe only under attack, or more rarely than things lying around. The whole point of the Bobblehead Stand (N.B. the game spells it with no space, as I wrote it in my question before your edit ;) is to display them, so it's annoying if they aren't safe.

Comment: well, bummer...

Comment: Unfortunately none of the settlers still have them in their inventory (so I killed them all). Now I regret setting them up a pool table with an almost full set of pool balls (and even chalk for the cues!) and cigars and bourbon. Not only was it a waste of time but the thieving swines don't deserve it. Sigh.

Comment: murder seems an appropriate response for theft

Comment: @boomstick I had my magazines get blown out of the rack by wind (or so it appeared). I found that clicking the transfer button on the rack and then backing out put them all back in the rack nice and neatly. I didn't even try picking them up off the ground, not sure what that would have done. If you have a recent save, you could try going back and clicking on the transfer. Maybe some fell through the ground and will magically get put back in place.

Answer (score 0):

> Is someone likely to have picked them up?

kalina answered this, and I've accepted that answer.

> Could they have gone back to their original spawn points? (and even if not, could I find a second copy by going back to those places?)

You can find another copy of **some** magazines by returning to the original location, but this doesn't seem to be true for all of them.

Now I'm going to build a fence around my "chill out area" (jukebox, mirrorball, bobblehead stand, magazine rack). If my settlers can't resist stealing my stuff then they don't get to enjoy the nice things I built for them ;-)