# Fallout 4 PS4: Are the character outfits bugged?

Tags: fallout-4

I have had to load a previous saved game (again), only this time Kellogg's outfit, the minute men General's Uniform, and the Silver Shroud outfit have vanished from my workbench. Is this another bug?

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: How to [stop people from stealing stuff](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247649/how-do-i-stop-my-settlers-stealing-my-weapons-and-armour).